# ASP.NET custom control with complex properties

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I'm developing a custom control (4.0), and I wonder how to reuse a business class as property without rewrite it.

I've a set of class in my business layer assembly (simplified):

```
public class LatLng
{
    public decimal Lat { get; set; } 
    public decimal Lng { get; set; } 
}

public class MapOptions
{
    ...
    public LatLng Center { get; set; } 
    ...
}

etc...
```

What I want is to reuse the MapOptions class as property, my custom control is something like:

```
public class MyControl : WebControl
{
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public MapOptions MapOptions 
    {
        ...

        get 
        {
            return this.ViewState["MapOptions"] as MapOptions;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.ViewState["MapOptions"] = value;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

But in this way I'm not able to see the properties of the LatLng (and of the other classes used as properties by MapOptions) as inner section of MapOptions tag. Only as attribute. 
So in the markup I'm able to write:

```
<rec:MyControl ID="control1" runat="server" Width="900" Height="500">
    <MapOptions Center="" />
</rec:MyControl>
```

But in this way I'm losing the intellisense for all exposed by LatLng, I'm searching a solution to obtain this:

```
<rec:MyControl ID="control1" runat="server" Width="900" Height="500">
    <MapOptions>
        <Center Lat="12.0" Lng="2.0" />
    </MapOptions>
</rec:MyControl>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding tag
`[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]`
to `public class LatLng`